# Put HTML tabs using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to put tabs created using JQueryUI in my existing HTML page. I have created  to display HTML content received using Ajax. But tabs are not shown correctly. Below is my ajax function

```
function GetVendorProfile(Category,Business) {
var xmlhttp;    
if ((Category== 0) || (Business == 0))  {
  document.getElementById("ShowVendorProfile").innerHTML="Please select Category";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {     document.getElementById("ShowVendorProfile").innerHTML=
                   xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
if ((Category == "Function Hall") && (Business != 0)){
    xmlhttp.open("GET","vendorprofile.php?Business="+Business,true);
}
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

My vendorprofile.php contains simple tabs. Pls let me know if there is any other way to display HTML successfully using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Jquery load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

You can easily load from server directly to html:

```
$("#ShowVendorProfile").load("vendorprofile.php?Business="+Business);
```